# [iOS]How to get the Calendar Event, one Recurrence as one event?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, icalendar, eventkit, recurrence

I get calendar event as the following code:

```
NSDate *startDate1 = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *endDate1 = [NSDate distantFuture];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate1 endDate:endDate1 calendars:calendarArray];
    NSArray *events = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
```

But if I add a recurrence event, if the frequency is every week, the 'events' will has 209 objects; if a event frequency is every 2 week, 'events' will have 105 objects.
I compute the time, it is 4 years of time also.

How can I get the event, one recurrence event only has one object?

//I'm testing using event.eventIdentifier...

Answer (score 1):

Repeated events has a read-only property 'isDetached'.

Also, you can find the details about recurrence rules, etc. in:

WWDC 2010 videos, Session 136 Calendar Integration with Event Kit.

Comment: //===============The following added by Annie Wang======= Sorry, it seems the isDetached always be NO, no matter it is repeat or not repeat. Suppose recurrence event, isDetached = YES, one-time event, isDetached = NO; how to get all the event list, one recurrence event only get one object?

I do the following work: 1. get all the different eventIdentifier 2. find the event with different eventIdentifier

It works!